# How to escape hash symbol in sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

I have the following text in my .rst file:

```
This is an example::

    #! /usr/bin/env python
```

The result is a line in italics because of the symblol '#' instead of a normal (tt) text.

How do I escape this meaning of '#'?

Comment: BTW, using '\#" did not work -- both symbols '\' and '#' appear, even though as normal tt text!